# How char arr[] = "OX|-" works in c language

Tags: c, arrays, or-operator

I am a beginner to c and I came across this line

```
char arr[] = "OX|-";

printf("%4c",arr[6]); //it prints -
```

1. how it prints `-` here?
2. does `|` operator works in array of any type in such a fashion?
3. does this line works in other languages like java, c#?

Comment: this may be a very silly question..and u have downvoted..no problem..atleast suggest me an idea ..so that  i can understand how it printed "-"

Comment: The posted code invokes *undefined behavior*. Your first question is thus senseless to try and answer, as you're asking for definition where there is none. Your second question make no sense, as there is no `operator |` (bitwise OR) being used in the two lines you posted. Your third question seems to be asking whether other language exhibit similar behavior. *That* question *can* be answered: Some may, some may not.

Comment: "*how it prints - here?*" what would expect to happen?

Answer (score 0):

This is because of the way variables are stored on the stack. By referencing arr[6] you have blown past the end of your array (which is only 5 bytes) and is now referencing another region of memory. Whatever happens to be stored there is what will be printed by that call. The | is not an operator here.